# Is it possible to give IAM users root access in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The question is self explanatory. I am the root account holder in AWS.I would like to give make one of my team members(IAM user) a root user.

Comment: No, you can't do this to my knowledge. Are you sure it's actually necessary? There's [very little a non-root user can't do](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_tasks-that-require-root.html) (with the right permissions, of course).

Comment: What problem do you have? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the account owner is the root user. You may create IAM users which has -almost root- privileges.

For operational tasks you do not need root account and you should not use the root account.